# Trouble animating dynamically created boxes in ThreeJS (3js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Ill try to make this short, i've never had luck asking questions online before.

So basically i wrote a for-loop in JS in order to dynamically create multiple box meshes so that i may animate them with 3js

```js
var ghostBoxes = 10;
var boxes = [];

meshX = -10;
for (var i = 0; i < ghostBoxes; i++) {
  var ghostBox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  ghostBox.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  ghostBox.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  ghostBox.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  scene.add(ghostBox);
  boxes.push(ghostBox);
  meshX += 1;
}
```

This script seems to work well because they appear just fine. Furthermore, when i console.log(boxes.length) i am returned integer 10 so i suspect im successfully populating the array.

However, when i try to animate all ten (with some simple x and y axis rotations) i can only get one to box to animate (and only on one axis) see below...

```js
var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  for (var i = 0; i < ghostBoxes; i++) {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax();
    this.tl.to(boxes[i].rotation.x += 0.01, {x: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut});
    this.tl.to(boxes[i].rotation.y += 0.01, {x: .5, ease: Expo.easeOut});
  }
};
```

furthermore i get the endless compiling error of ...

"TweenMax.min.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'repeat' of undefined
    at d.s.to (TweenMax.min.js:14)
    at render (main.js:52)"

js 52 is the second line of code from the bottom where i try to rotate on the 'x' axis.

My structure could be way off as well. I've tried many things but its hard for me to try much more. Im completely stuck. I've only been coding for 3 months so please be gentle.

===> the code in whole below

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  75,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000,
);
camera.position.z = 20;

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 1000);
light.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(light);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 2, 1000);
light.position.set(0, 0, 25);
scene.add(light);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setClearColor('#ffffff');
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xf7f7f7 });

var ghostBoxes = 10;
var boxes = [];

meshX = -10;
for (var i = 0; i < ghostBoxes; i++) {
  var ghostBox = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  ghostBox.position.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  ghostBox.position.y = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  ghostBox.position.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 10;
  scene.add(ghostBox);
  boxes.push(ghostBox);
  meshX += 1;
}

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  for (var i = 0; i < ghostBoxes; i++) {
    this.tl = new TimelineMax();
    this.tl.to(boxes[i].rotation.x += 0.01, {x: 2, ease: Expo.easeOut});
    this.tl.to(boxes[i].rotation.y += 0.01, {x: .5, ease: Expo.easeOut});
  }
};

render(boxes);
// ghostBox.rotation.x += 0.01;
// ghostBox.rotation.y += 0.01;
```

Thank You

Comment: Hello Eugenio, welcome to StackOverflow. As far as the Three.js side of things, everything is looking good. However you are utilizing the TimelineMax function incorrectly. Check the [documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/v2/TimelineMax/to()) for more information on how to use it.

Comment: Here's a small [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/73dkb5ce/8/) with the correct usage of `to()` function.

Comment: wow, no way! I’ll give it a shot ASAP and let you know. Thanks tons